# Drawing polygon around a raster (only where pixels have data) QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I have a raster (grey scale image with white background [can change to e.g. green]).
I want to make a polygon of the extent of the pixels with data (outline)- not the whole raster file.

How can I do this in QGIS?

Also can you do this for many rasters in a group (e.g. a mosaic of rasters making a larger image)

Comment: Does your image have an alpha band, or is the white background marked as nodata? Are there white pixels also in the data area? How did you plan to change background of a grey-scale image into green?